# How can we restrict some account from making a transaction on chain?

Tags: pallet, proxy

I am using the proxy account. Can I restrict the main account to make transactions on the chain, so the transaction can be done only from the proxy account?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really, but you could lose the private key by "mistake", or what is similar, create an *anonymous proxy* where the calling account becomes a proxy of a newly generated account that exists only on-chain and has no known private key, therefore no transactions can be signed directly by it.

Comment: Agree, you should probably use Anonymous Proxy for this, just be careful not to restrict the proxy type (it should be `Any`) or else you will not be able to transfer the tokens.

Comment: Yup, after creating the anonymous account and add some more account as controllers, you can safely remove the creator from the anonymous proxy account.